# How to keep wiremock stubs in sync with provider api?

Tags: wiremock, pact

How do we keep the mocks in wiremocks in sync with the production api ?. How do we avoid drift between the mocks and the production api ?

I tried writing pact tests towards wiremock to test if they are in complaince but im not sure if that is the correct method to follow.

Comment: Just wondering if i can use Pact to do this and if its a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but have you considered using something like https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/ ?

Comment: Nope. But it looks like it can do the job.